# Custom console input code, sometimes wrong output

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, segmentation-fault, allocation

I was testing my code by writing bunch of characters and "correcting" it by using backspace a couple of times in quick succession. Normally the code works but after that brutal treatment the output consists of few letters from the screen and bunch of null characters afterwards. I want to spam proof that function.

The function gets a character from the keyboard then checks if the char is a enter, backspace or lowercase, capital letter
if it is a enter it adds a null char on the end and returns,
if it is a letter it expands the array of chars by one and adds the char at the end.
if it is a backspace it creates another array 1 smaller than previous one and moves 1 element less from the original array to the new one. After that it deletes old array and assigns the new one to the old pointer.

I even fixed the null pointer bug that occurred randomly.

Do anybody have any ideas why does it outputs trash?
Is there a way to clear the input buffer before it loads another char?

```
char* readString()
    {
        int current_char=0;
        char *char_ptr;

        do{
        char_ptr = (char*)calloc(1,sizeof(char));
        }while(char_ptr==NULL);

        while(true)
        {

            char c = getch();

            if(c==13)
            {
                *(char_ptr+current_char)=0;
                printf("\n\n");

                for(int i=0;i<current_char+1;i++)
                {
                    printf("%i \n", *(char_ptr+i));
                }
                return char_ptr;
            }
            if((97<=c && c<=112) || (65<=c && c<=90))
            {
                printf("%c",c);
                *(char_ptr+current_char)=c;
                current_char++;

                do
                {
                    char_ptr = (char*)realloc(char_ptr, sizeof(char)*(current_char+1));
                }while(char_ptr==NULL);


            }
            if(c==8)
            {
                if(current_char==0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                printf("%c",c);
                printf(" ");
                printf("%c",c);
                current_char--;
                if(current_char==0)
                {
                    free(char_ptr);

                    do{
                    char_ptr = (char*)calloc(1,sizeof(char));
                    }while(char_ptr==NULL);

                }
                else
                {
                    char * next_pointer;

                    do{
                    next_pointer = (char*)calloc((current_char+1),sizeof(char));
                    }while(next_pointer==NULL);

                    memccpy(next_pointer, char_ptr, (current_char), sizeof(char));

                    free(char_ptr);
                    char_ptr=next_pointer;
                    next_pointer=NULL;
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Looks like you misread the `memccpy` description. Pay attention to the last two arguments. There are plenty other problems, but address this first.

Comment: Ahh that was the mistake... I didnt realise that i had used the wrong function!
It is supposed to be memcpy not memccpy...
Just a stupid typo. Thanks for help!

Comment: OT: `if((97<=c && c<=112) || (65<=c && c<=90))` is unecessary hard to read. Why not `if (('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z'))`? It's easier to read and produces the exact same code. You may also have a look at [`isalpha()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha). (It's usually implemented as look-up in a table.)

Comment: Oops. I just realized that 112 is the ASCII of `'p'`. Either, you made a typo and meant 122 (ASCII of `'z'`) or my above recommendation should be fixed appropriately. However, it shows impressively why it makes sense to use character constants instead of integer constants for character comparisons. ;-)

Comment: `do {char_ptr = (char*)calloc(1,sizeof(char));} while(char_ptr==NULL);` is a horrible way to allocate and validate. If `calloc` fails, it failed for a reason and it will likely fail for the exact same reason continually resulting in an infinite loop. Further calling `calloc` to allocate a single character is pointless. You use 8-bytes for the pointer, plus the `calloc` call to allocate 1-char? Even in a `realloc` scheme, incremental allocation by `1-byte` is horribly inefficient. Also see: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: And `getch()` is not a standard function and is better avoided.